# Entity Framework, AspNetUsers FK error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a project using MVC5 with Identity and Entity Framework.
I used database first, and i created lot of tables with the ASPNetUser.Id as FK.
So, for example i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](5000) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Logs] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Log_DateTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateTime]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Logs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Log_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Logs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Log_AspNetUsers]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Logs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Log_LogType] FOREIGN KEY([LogTypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LogTypes] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Logs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Log_LogType]
GO
```

So, i created my EntityFramework 6 edmx and i added all my tables, including this one.

After that, i used Scaffolding for the CRUDs, and it created the Controller and the Views very well.

But... when i played all the project, on the Index view it throws an error on the line:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var logs = db.Logs.Include(l => l.LogType);
            return View(logs.ToList());  //----->>> HERE THROWS THE ERROR
        }
```

The error:

> Invalid column name 'AspNetUser_Id'.

The query tried to run:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[LogTypeId] AS [LogTypeId], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[DateTime] AS [DateTime], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description1], 
    [Extent1].[AspNetUser_Id] AS [AspNetUser_Id] //---> THIS FIELD DOES NOT EXISTS !!! 
    FROM  [dbo].[Logs] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LogTypes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[LogTypeId] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

So, do you know why it s looking for ASPNetUser_Id? That field does not exists. 
And also, why with the other FK works fine??

I ve tried without success to:

- Create the emdx again
- Update the edmx from the Database
- Change the FK's name

Any idea???

Thanks for everything guys !!

Comment: Are you sure `AspNetUser_Id` is the name of the field?  I'm looking at a table that I used EF5 DBFirst and its just called `Id` from the `AspNewUsers` table

Comment: There is no AspNetUser_Id field on my entire database. in AspNetUsers exists "Id", but the error says there is no column named "AspNetUser_Id" but on my FK table (Logs). That s the issue :(

Comment: Done !!!! ... the issue was when you create the new item on scaffolding popup window it shows you 2 connection strings available, you must choose the Entity Framework one. Thats all !!!